# Catch an exception and re-throw as boost exception

Tags: c++, boost, boost-exception

I am trying to use Boost exceptions for the additional metadata that I can attach to exceptions as they bubble up the call stack. But one use case I have encountered but do not know how to handle is: how do I catch a std::exception and wrap that with a boost exception and throw/rethrow the wrapped exception? For example:

```
try {
    CallFunctionThatThrowsStdException();
} catch(std::exception& ex) {
    MyBoostException bex{ex};
    bex << "Add metadata for this call scenario";
    throw bex;
}
```

What is a good open source project that uses Boost.Exception to study?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to wrap a `std::exception`?   Why not copy data (e.g. the result of its `what()` member function) from the `std::exception` into the metadata of the boot exception?

Comment: Well, at the least I would like to capture the exception type in addition to the ``what()`` string. But some exceptions contain more than just the what string, so I was being idealistic in hoping that I could simply wrap the entire exception.